# XSLT: processing inner XML

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I'm trying to process XML inner text. I have the following XSLT snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="refsect1[@id='errors']/param">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="param/constant">
        <i><xsl:apply-templates/></i>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="param/parameter">
        <paramref cref="{.}"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

    <xsl:template name="summary" match="refentry">
/// <summary>
/// <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(
                    substring(refnamediv/refpurpose, 1, 1), $lowercase, $uppercase),
                    substring(refnamediv/refpurpose, 2, string-length(refnamediv/refpurpose) - 1))"/>
/// </summary>
        <xsl:for-each select="refsect1/variablelist/varlistentry">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../../@id = 'parameters'">
/// <param name="{term/parameter}">
        <xsl:for-each select="listitem/para">
/// <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
/// </param>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// This routine generates the following errors (detectable with <see cref="Gl.GetError"/>):
        <xsl:for-each select="refsect1[@id='errors']/para">
/// <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
        <xsl:for-each select="refsect1[@id = 'seealso']/para/citerefentry">
/// <seealso cref="Gl.{substring(refentrytitle, 3)}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT shall be applied to a XML document; here is a snippet:

```
<refsect1 id="errors"><title>Errors</title>
    <para>
        <constant>GL_INVALID_OPERATION</constant> is generated if <parameter>pipeline</parameter> is not
        a name previously returned from a call to <citerefentry><refentrytitle>glGenProgramPipelines</refentrytitle></citerefentry>
        or if such a name has been deleted by a call to
        <citerefentry><refentrytitle>glDeleteProgramPipelines</refentrytitle></citerefentry>.
    </para>
    <para>
        <constant>GL_INVALID_OPERATION</constant> is generated if <parameter>program</parameter> refers
        to a program object that has not been successfully linked.
    </para>
</refsect1>
```

My current output is actually a plain text:

```
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// This routine generates the following errors (detectable with <see cref="Gl.GetError" />):
/// GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if pipeline is not a name previously returned from a call to glGenProgramPipelines or if such a name has been deleted by a call to glDeleteProgramPipelines.
/// GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if program refers to a program object that has not been successfully linked.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
```

but I'd like to to process it in order to transform the internal tags in other tags. For example:

*<costant>text</constant>* shall become *<i>text</i>*

and

*<parameter>GL_PARAM</parameter>*  shall become *<paramref cref="Gl.PARAM"/>*

---

How to achieve this result?

---

After that Alexander has helped me, I got I have to call xsl:apply-template. It starting to work, but I cannot control the space normalization:

```
/// <para>
/// This routine generates the following errors (detectable with <see cref="Gl.GetError" />):
    <i>GL_INVALID_OPERATION</i> is generated if <paramref cref="pipeline" /> is not
        a name previously returned from a call to glGenProgramPipelines
        or if such a name has been deleted by a call to
        glDeleteProgramPipelines.
    <i>GL_INVALID_OPERATION</i> is generated if <paramref cref="program" /> refers
        to a program object that has not been successfully linked.

/// </para>
```

I'm calling xsl:apply-template just after the *foreach* instruction:

```
/// <para>
/// This routine generates the following errors (detectable with <see cref="Gl.GetError"/>):
    <xsl:for-each select="refsect1[@id='errors']/para">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:for-each>
/// </para>
```

Comment: The actual problem is that it seems not possible to control space normalization (I requires one line or multiple lines starting with ///).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the trick is to understand the power of functional and declarative programming. You've got a very imperative style at the moment, so let's rewrite it a bit ;

```
<xsl:template match="refsect1[@id='errors']/param">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="param/constant">
   <i><xsl:apply-templates /></i>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="param/parameter">
   <paramref cref="{.}" />
</xsl:template>
```

That's roughly all you need. Basically, instead of going through all parts of your XML and try to do something at that point, use the templating system to match the items in question and have it done far more efficient and powerful.

Lastly, if your GL_PARAM to Gl.PARAM wasn't a typo, you need to do some extra text transformation on top, but it isn't that hard if you know the formula (you didn't say :), using something like before-substring(), after-substring(), and translate().

Comment: It would be great, but it doesn't work to me (question updated). I can call xsl:call-template (if I'm right), but it would be more imperative, isn't?

Comment: Furthermore, I think template shall match *para/parameter* and *para/constant* and */refsect1[@id='errors']/para* (not *param*). Is it right?

Comment: Nope. I can't see any match with the template, and I cannot see why!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll check it better in the morning (wife already in bed demanding lights out, so I better head ...)

Comment: And yes, 'para' rather than 'param'. :) It should work fine, however I suspect the problem is that your input XML isn't completely what you give in your example, probably some wrapper code of sorts. If you can get to where the para starts and <xsl:apply-templates /> from there, it should work.

Comment: Yes, the XML in my question is only a snippet. Is it a problem?